# Calling jQuery event handler on click : anonymous vs named function behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery

Playing around with the .on('click', ) event and I get differing behaviour based on whether I supply an anonymous vs named function (the named function doesn't work). Is this a syntax error?

```
<div id="myID"> abc </div>

<script>
  $("#myID").on('click',function(e){
            console.log(e.type);
  }); //works

  function handle(e){
    console.log(e.type);
  }

  $("#myID").on('click',handle(e)); //doesn't work

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to replace

```
 $("#myID").on('click',handle(e));
```

with

```
 $("#myID").on('click',handle);
```

Comment: thanks, it works. How does the function know about the event "e" if it's not passed in?

Comment: The event object is passed by default to the function

Comment: That's strange... do you know of any other instances where this happens in JS?

Comment: It happens all the time when callback function is passed as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

When you call a function, it is executed immediately. This happens when you do

```js
$("#myID").on('click',handle(e));
```

You call the function, passing an event `e` which does not exist yet. What you want instead is giving jQuery a function that it should call when the user clicks on the element with the id `myID`.

This is possible in JavaScript because it has first-class functions. This means that if you create a function like this:

```js
function handle(e){
  console.log(e.type);
}
```

then you get a reference to the function that you just created. This reference is stored in a variable named `handle`. You could achieve the same if you do:

```js
var handle = function (e) { // create a function and store a reference to it in a variable
  console.log(e.type);
};
```

The function takes an argument `e`. This doesn't exist yet, it has to exist in the moment you call the function:

```js
handle(e); // ReferenceError: e is not defined
```

You can pass the reference to that function to jQuery, which then calls your function when the user clicks the element. At that point, `e` still doesn't exist, because it will contain information about the event, which hasn't occured yet. It will look like this:

```js
$("#myID").on('click', handle); // pass a reference to the handle function to jQuery
```

Now, `handle` doesn't get called, because you only pass a reference to the function. You could say that you pass the function as an argument to another (jQuery) function. This is called a callback function.

#### *Edit*

Note that all functions that were created above take `e` as their argument. The argument doesn't have to exist in the very moment you create the function. However, when you (or jQuery) call the function, you have to provide an argument so that the function can do its job.

It's the same with an unnamed function: you create the function, but the argument does not exist yet. When you (or jQuery) call the function, you have to provide an argument.

This means there is no essential difference. The only difference is that one function has a name, the other one doesn't. You could even do this:

```js
$("#myID").on('click', function handle (e) { // pass a reference to the function, but do not call it
  console.log(e.type);
});
```

... which has the same effect as:

```js
$("#myID").on('click', function (e) { // pass a reference to the function, but do not call it
  console.log(e.type);
});
```

... except that in the first example, you keep a reference to the function that you created in a variable called "handle". In the second example, you lose the reference to the function, and only jQuery will be able to use your function.

*Edit end*

Another example for that would be:

```js
var testFunction = function (arg) {
  console.log('My argument is:', arg);
};

var executeTwoTimes = function (callback) { // accept a callback function as the first argument
  callback('foo'); // execute the callback function
  callback('foo');
};

executeTwoTimes(testFunction); // pass a reference to testFunction
// or:
executeTwoTimes(function (a) { // pass a reference to an anonymous function 
  console.log(a + ' bar');
});
```

I hope I could make things clearer for you.

Comment: Thanks Peter. You say that passing the argument "e" doesn't work in the named function because "e" doesn't exist yet (I can accept that), however the anonymous function can take "e"....so what's the essential difference between the two?